# Laravel 5 Parse

Tags: php, parse-platform, laravel-5

I have the following problem i'm using laravel 5 and laraparse package.Login with parse works without a problem,also things like insert categories works.The problem is for sign up i'm using ParseUser().I use the following code from parse docs for sign up:

```
$user = new ParseUser();
$user->set("username", $request->username);
$user->set("email", $request->email);
$user->set('isArtist', $isArtist);
$user->set("password", $request->password);


try {
    $user->signUp();

    return redirect('profile');

} catch (ParseException $ex) {
    // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
    echo "Error: " . $ex->getCode() . " " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

but it returns the following error:
You must specify a Parse class name or register the appropriate subclass when creating a new Object. Use ParseObject::create to create a subclass object.
The keys in config are ok because login and everything else works so the keys are not the problem.